# How do i force a stream to wait for the interval() operator to complete before executing the rest of the stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My problem is the following: My webapplication uses auth tokens that can expire. When they are about to expire a 401 error is sent by the server prompting the browser to do a token refresh request first. I am using the `retryWhen()` operator to handle this situation. The`retryWhen()` operator uses the following code to request a new token.

```
  public tokenExpired = ({
    maxRetryAttempts = 1
  }: {
    maxRetryAttempts?: number,
  } = {}) => (attempts: Observable<any>) => {
    return attempts.pipe(
      mergeMap((error, i) => {
        const retryAttempt = i + 1;
        if((error && error.headers && (!error.headers.get("reason-unauthorized") || !(error.headers.get("reason-unauthorized") === "authentication-token-expires-soon"))) || retryAttempt > maxRetryAttempts) {
          return throwError(error);
        }
          return this.requestNewToken().pipe(
            concatMap(refreshStatus => {
              if(refreshStatus === TokenRefreshStatus.TOKEN_REFRESHED) 
                return timer(0);
              else if(refreshStatus === TokenRefreshStatus.TOKEN_REFRESH_FAILED) 
                return throwError(error);
              else if(refreshStatus === TokenRefreshStatus.AWAIT_REFRESH && this.loggedIn.value){
                let maxWaitTimeInMilliSeconds = 4000; 
                interval(100).pipe(takeWhile(() => !(this.tokenRefreshStatus !== TokenRefreshStatus.AWAIT_REFRESH || maxWaitTimeInMilliSeconds <=0)))
                  .subscribe(value => {maxWaitTimeInMilliSeconds -= 100;});
                if(this.tokenRefreshStatus === TokenRefreshStatus.TOKEN_REFRESHED)
                  return timer(0); 
                else return throwError(error);
                }
              else 
                return throwError(error); 
            }));
      })
    );
  }
```

So the retryWhen operator will have `tokenExpired` as its lambda `retryWhen(tokenExpired())`. Because multiple requests could be fired nearly simultaneously I have made the code in such a way that only the first request will trigger a token refresh http request via `this.requestNewToken()` and any other request who makes a similar call through `retryWhen` will get a `AWAIT_REFRESH` message from the `requestNewToken()` method. This way I prevent multiple requests for a new token.

When AWAIT_REFRESH is received, the code must check every 100 milliseconds whether the `tokenRefreshStatus` has changed to either `TOKEN_REFRESHED`, or `TOKEN_REFRESH_FAILED`. It can repeat this for now longer then about 4000 milliseconds. Therefore the interval must also stop repeating when `maxWaitTimeInMilliSeconds` has reached 0 or below. After that there is a if statement that checks whether `TokenRefreshStatus` equals `TOKEN_REFRESHED`, if it does it sends back `timer(0)` if it doesn't it throws the original error received by the `retryWhen` operator.

My problem is that the app does not wait for the interval code to finish. It just goes straight to the if statement under that causing it to always throw an error. I think i should not subscribe to the interval but instead i should return it as a new observable that does the interval iterating AND the check after that to see if the token has refreshed after the interval completed. I just don't know how i should do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that the app does not wait for the interval code to finish.

That happens because interval creates an observable, which is asynchronous. I'd try making your refreshStatus function async to call await when you want it to wait (i.e: wrapping your interval in a promise to await for it):

```
concatMap(async refreshStatus => {
     .
     .
     .

     function checkit(){
       return new Promise((res, rej)=>{

        interval(100).pipe(takeWhile(() =>{
          if(!(this.tokenRefreshStatus !== TokenRefreshStatus.AWAIT_REFRESH || maxWaitTimeInMilliSeconds <=0)){
            return true;
          }
          else{
            res(true);
            return false;
          }
        }))
        .subscribe(value => {maxWaitTimeInMilliSeconds -= 100;});
      });
    }
    await checkit();

     .
     .
     .
})
```

I hope that helps you solve your problem.